# Unity materials appear broken

Tags: unity-game-engine, import

I've recently imported a Unity project that references .fbx file.

When I imported the project (which was created by another user) all surfaces are pink.

Having looked at all the materials the following is observed

- All the materials in the top level materials are present but are shades of grey not as the material should appear
- At specific assest level (assets->material_name->material) there are no materials
- All textures are present
- All objects have a material associated with them which are all from the grey materials.

I can force change a material by selecting the surface and manually changing the material from its default to the one material which isn't grey "teleport" for all three surface materials.

There is a seemingly related error at the bottom "speedtree materials need to be regenerated". I've googled this however, the only solution was to select the prefab option in the assets list which is not an existing option in my project.

Any thoughts would be awesome.

CBusBus

Comment: Did you check my answer? Is your issue fixed?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't solve my problem. The shader exists in my project already and the materials are present also, I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shader problem. Please note that shader is not the-same as material. You plug shader into a material. The circled image below shows a "Standard" Shader that is attached to a material named "CubeMat2".

[image]

The imported Object can be pink because:

**1**.The shader is missing in the Project.

Manually copy the shader into your project and re-attach it to your material.

**2**.The shader is obsolete or uses a keyword that's not available your current version of Unity.

Make sure you are using the-same version of Unity *"another user"* used to create the original project.

**3**.A simple import bugs. This happens somethings.

All you have to do is select the material, change the shader to another Shader then change it back to what it was before. For some reason, this seems to fix the issue.

**4**.There is an error in the shader. If there an error in the shader, Unity can't compile it and it will be pink when attached to a material. Also, if there is a shader error, you will see that in the Console tab. You will have to fix that error.